# Styling Listboxes with special final ListBoxItem (Silverlight 5/WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

If I am styling a list box, sometimes I'll have a divider between each element. BUT I don't want that divider below the final element.

[image: the problem]

Is there some sort of converter trickery I can use to get this? (Silverlight 5)

Answer thanks to the below post:

XAML:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="SilverlightApplication41.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication41"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:NotLastItemToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NotLastItemToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Border Background="#EEEDED" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ListBox x:Name="_listbox" Background="#FFEEEDED" BorderBrush="#FF585858">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="2">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Height="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="1,0,1,-2"
                                       Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NotLastItemToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

CS:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SilverlightApplication41
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            // Required to initialize variables
            InitializeComponent();
            List<string> dataList = new List<string>(){"Ants", "Bats", "Cats", "Dogs", "Entoloma sinuatum"};
            ((NotLastItemToVisibilityConverter)Resources["NotLastItemToVisibilityConverter"]).DataList = dataList;
            _listbox.ItemsSource = dataList;
        }

    }

    public class NotLastItemToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public List<string> DataList {get; set;}

        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(DataList.Count == 0 || (string)value == DataList[DataList.Count-1])
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

***Note:*** The comparison needs to be an object comparison OR unique strings in the list. Otherwise the list A,B,A would only have a divider after B since "A" == "A". So this is a bad example using a string but makes the point. I tried casting DataList[DataList.Count-1] to an object but it doesn't seem that the binding uses the exact string passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there will be some converter trickery.

Bind the visibility of the divider to the list item. Then in the converter check return `true` if it's not the `.Last()` item in the list and `false` if it is. You will need to get access to the view model in the converter.

I don't have the code to hand right now, but I've done something similar to this to enable/disable buttons.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I'll write the code and throw it in the original post.